# Vue saves image on wrong component when file @change is used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, filereader

I have an image component, like a slider, where the user can append an extra image to the end of the slider.
However if there are more than one of the same slider component on the page, it always adds the image to the first component.

DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-sid-71ox2?file=/src/components/ImageBlock.vue

Btw. I have other components that don't use the filereader API which works as expected. Same approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having dulicated id for `extra_image`. Thus every click on label `+` is firing the first hidden file input.

To fix this, you just need to give different ids based on `block_index`:

```
    <input
      :id="`extra_image_${block_index}`"
      class="hidden"
      name="extra_image"
      type="file"
      accept="image/*"
      @change="add_extra_image($event)"
    >
    <label :for="`extra_image_${block_index}`" class="extra_image">
      <span class="icon">+</span>
    </label>
```